# Python Pie chart in Matplotlib or Altair from two categorical data

Tags: python

This is my sample data frame

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| Paris | Gas |
| Paris | Solar |
| Paris | Solar |
| London | Oil |
| London | Solar |
| London | Oil |

I want to create pie charts based on all unique data points based on Column A with pie chart size coming from Column B. For example, for this data base, I want a pie chart for Paris and one for London.
How can I do this in one code?
Thank you

Comment: So, the counts of column B define the segment sizes of the pie charts? What have you tried, why did it fail?

Comment: yes, counts of column B define the segment sizes of the pie charts. I have been doing separately for each (London/Paris). Not sure how to do it together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way, I think, is to cross-tabulate your data:

```
#data generation
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)
n=20
city = np.random.choice(["Paris", "London"], n)
cat = np.random.choice(["Gas", "Oil", "Sun"], n)

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": city, "B": cat})

#count the numbers occurrence of each category in an A x B table
df_count = df.pivot_table(index="B", columns="A", fill_value=0, aggfunc="size")

#plot the pie chart using pandas convenience wrapper for matplotlib
ax = df_count.plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(10, 5))

plt.show()
```

Sample output:
[image]

For a quick overview, [pandas plotting routine](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.pie.html) is sufficient. For better control over the final image, you may want to plot `df_count` directly using matplotlib.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
df_2 = df.groupby(["A"])['B'].nunique()
plt.pie(df_2, labels = df_2.index, autopct='%.0f%%')
plt.show()
```

Output: 
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I was looking for the outputs in the above answer